# Save array of data

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, arraylist

I have use jquery in adding new input type as long as the user want it.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("addBatch_CARF", "CARF", FormMethod.Post, new { @name = "register" }))
    {
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div id="formAlert" class="alert alert-danger">  
            <a class="close">×</a>  
            <strong>Warning!</strong> Make sure all fields are filled and try again.
        </div>

        var catName = "";
        var displayCan = "";
        var candidates = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            if (catName != Model[i].request_category)
            {
            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[i].request_category)
                <span class="pull-right" style="margin-right:60px;">Special Instructions</span>
            </li>
                catName = Model[i].request_category;
                displayCan = catName;

            }
            if (displayCan == Model[i].request_category)
            {
                candidates = Model[i].request_name;
            <div class="checkbox_request">
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model[i].isSelected, new { @class = "is_selected" }) 

                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].request_name)
                    @if(Model[i].request_name == "Folder Access")
                    {
                        <span class="label label-danger">Pls specify all the drive path. Note: For accessing of drives outside PETC please proceed to Online CARF</span>
                    }
                <span class="pull-right">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].special_instruction)
                </span>
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].request_type_id)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].system_roles_id)
            </div>
            }

        }
        <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">
        Access to:
        </li>

    <div class="input_fields_wrap">
        <button class="add_field_button btn btn-primary">Add More Fields</button>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="fname[]" placeholder="First Name">
            <input type="text" name="lname[]" placeholder="Last Name">
            <input type="text" name="email_add[]" placeholder="Email Address">
            <input type="text" name="user_id[]" placeholder="User ID">
        </div>
    </div>

    <p class="request_btn">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="addbtn">Save</button>
    </p>
    }
```

Javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
            var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
            var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

            var x = 1; //initlal text box count
            $(add_button).click(function (e) { //on add input button click
                e.preventDefault();
                if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
                    x++; //text box increment
                    $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="fname[]" placeholder="First Name"/>&nbsp;<input type="text" name="lname[]" placeholder="Last Name"/>&nbsp;<input type="text" name="email_add[]" placeholder="Email Add"/>&nbsp;<input type="text" name="user_id[]" placeholder="User ID"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
                }
            });

            $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function (e) { //user click on remove text
                e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
            })
     </script>
```

How will I add this data to my database? I've tried this code in my controller but these following parameters have no values `string[] fname= null, string[] lname= null, string[] email_add= null, string[] user_id = null`.

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult addBatch_CARF(List<Request_Type> list = null, string[] fname= null, string[] lname= null, string[] email_add= null, string[] user_id = null)
        {
            var data = db.Employees_All_vw.Where(x => x.NT_Name == @User.Identity.Name.Remove(0, 9).ToLower() && x.active_flag == true).FirstOrDefault();
            //add data into CARF table
            CARF carf = new CARF();
            carf.requestor = data.Emp_Badge_No;
            carf.carf_type = "BATCH CARF";
            carf.created_by = @User.Identity.Name.Remove(0, 9).ToLower();
            carf.created_date = System.DateTime.Now;
            carf.active_flag = true;
            db.CARves.Add(carf);
            db.SaveChanges();
            int id = carf.carf_id;
            //add data into Request Access Table
            foreach (var i in list)
            {
                int val = 1;
                bool y = Convert.ToBoolean(val);
                if (i.isSelected == y)
                {
                    Request_Access ra = new Request_Access();
                    ra.request_access_id = 1;
                    ra.carf_id = id;
                    ra.request_type_id = i.request_type_id;
                    ra.special_instruction = i.special_instruction;
                    ra.ra_assignee = i.system_roles_id;
                    ra.dept_approval = null;
                    ra.dept_approval_date = null;
                    ra.dept_remarks = null;
                    ra.final_approval = null;
                    ra.final_approval_date = null;
                    ra.final_remarks = null;
                    ra.acknowledge_by = null;
                    ra.acknowledge_date = null;
                    ra.journal = null;
                    ra.closed_by = null;
                    ra.closed_date = null;
                    ra.verified_by = null;
                    ra.verified_date = null;
                    db.Request_Access.Add(ra);

                }
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            //add all list of names to the Batch CARF table
            for (var x = 1; x < fname.Count(); x++)
            {
            //foreach(var x in fname)
                Batch_CARF batch = new Batch_CARF();
                batch.carf_id = id;
                batch.fname = fname[x];
                batch.lname = lname[x];
                batch.email_add = email_add[x];
                batch.user_id = user_id[x];
                batch.active_flag = true;
                db.Batch_CARF.Add(batch);
            }
            db.SaveChanges();

            //send email notification to the data owner or final approver by batch
            TempData["MessageAlert"] = "Successfully created!";

            return RedirectToAction("Batch_CARF");
        }
```

Comment: You need to add indexers to the `name` attributes of your form controls and then you can bind to a model which is a collection of a type containing those properties (`fname`, `lname` etc). Its difficult from your code to understand what your trying to achieve with this, but refer the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161481/post-a-form-array-without-successful/29161796#29161796) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) for some options for dynamically adding collection items

Comment: You examples are way to complex. Simplify them and come back.

Comment: name = fname[] is not a valid name, especially if you have more than one.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12203913/dynamically-adding-items-into-view-and-posting-back-to-controller-asp-net-mvc-4/12205084#12205084) for an example of how to post a collection

Comment: So I need to render a partial view in adding those items since those data was came from other table and I have used already @model List<PETC_CARF.Models.Request_Type> model for this view

Comment: @Jen143Me. If you use a partial view then you need to use the `BeginCollectionItem()` helper (refer the links above). But the first thing you should be doing is to **stop** using data models in your view and use view models containing all the properties you need for editing

Comment: What should I do in my model and in my controller as well? I can't clearly understand the examples

Comment: @Jen143Me, What part do you not understand? Start by creating a view model (say `PersonVM`) with those 4 properties. In the POST method, you will have a parameter `List<PersonVM> persons`. Then in the view you create a template (outside the form element) with the 4 inputs that you then clone, update the indexer and add to the DOM.