# How can I post two or more models in one form?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-database-first

I'm working on an internet lesson plans application for a project. The lesson plan is built from following models (generated with Entity Framework in Database First approach):

```
public partial class Subject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Hour { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int DayId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int PlanId { get; set; }

    public virtual Day Day { get; set; }
    public virtual Plan Plan { get; set; }
}

public partial class Plan
{
    public Plan()
    {
        this.Przedmiot = new HashSet<Subjects>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Subject> Subject { get; set; }
}
```

I have no problems with displaying both models in one View, but I can't seem to figure out how to post both models to database when creating new plan. I want my View to look something like this: 
[image: My View]

So my question is what's the best approach here, and how can I create one record in Plan table in database, and many Subject records linked to it in this one view.

*Edit:*
Code with my display View as requested (omitted unnecessary parts because it's rather long):

```
@model IEnumerable<Lesson_plan.DAL.Subject>
<table style="border: 1px solid black; margin: 40px; width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <th>Hours</th>
        <th>Monday</th>
        <th>Tuesday</th>
        <th>Wednesday</th>
        <th>Thursday</th>
        <th>Friday</th>
        <th>Saturday</th>
        <th>Sunday</th>
    </tr>

    @{
        if (Model != null)
        {
            var r = 1;
            var t = 1;
            List<string> hours = new List<string>();
            foreach (var subject in Model)
            {
                if (!hours.Contains(subject.Hour))
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <textarea>    
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => subjest.Hour)
                            @{ hours.Add(subject.Hour); }
                            </textarea>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <textarea>  
                            @foreach (var subjectName in Model)
                            {
                                if (subjectName.Day.DayOfTheWeek.Equals("Monday") &&
                                    subject.Hour.Equals(subjetName.Hour))
                                {
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => subject.Name)
                                }
                            }   
                            </textarea>
                        </td>

//and so on for every day 

                        }
                    </tr>
                    r++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
</table>
```

Code of my Controller class (I did some experiments with Create method, but I'm posting original method here):

```
namespace Lesson_plan.Controllers
{
    public class PlansController : Controller
    {
        private readonly LessonPlanEntities db = new LessonPlanEntities();

        // GET: Plans
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var plans = db.Plan.ToList();
            return View(plans);
        }

        // GET: Plans/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
                return Create();
            var subjects = db.Subject.
                Where(x => x.PlanId == id).
                OrderByDescending(x => x.Hour).ToList();
            if (subjects.Count > 0)
                ViewBag.Title = subjects[0].Plan.Name;
            return View(subjects);
        }

        // GET: Plans/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Plan plan)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Plan.Add(plan);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(plan);
        }

        // GET: Plans/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            var plan = db.Plan.Find(id);
            if (plan == null)
                return HttpNotFound();
            return View(plan);
        }

        // POST: Plans/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Nazwa")] Plan plan)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(plan).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(plan);
        }

        // GET: Plans/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            var plan = db.Plan.Find(id);
            if (plan == null)
                return HttpNotFound();
            return View(plan);
        }

        // POST: Plans/Delete/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            var plan = db.Plan.Find(id);
            db.Plan.Remove(plan);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
                db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

*Edit2*
Code for the Create View with form:

```
@model Lesson_plan.DAL.Plan

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Plans"))
{
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(plan => plan.Name)<br/>
        @Html.TextAreaFor(plan => plan.Name)
    </div>
    <table style="border: 1px solid black; margin: 40px; width: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <th>Hours</th>
            <th>Monday</th>
            <th>Tuesday</th>
            <th>Wednesday</th>
            <th>Thursday</th>
            <th>Friday</th>
            <th>Saturday</th>
            <th>Sunday</th>
        </tr>
            @{
                for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
                {
                    <tr>  
                        //what sould i put here ?                    
                        <td><textarea></textarea></td>
                        <th><textarea></textarea></th>
                        <th><textarea></textarea></th>
                        <th><textarea></textarea></th>
                        <th><textarea></textarea></th>
                        <th><textarea></textarea></th>
                        <th><textarea></textarea></th>
                        <th><textarea></textarea></th>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
    </table>
    <p>
        <a type="button" class="btn btn-info" href=@Url.Action("Index")>Back</a>
        <input type="submit" value="Create"/>
    </p>
}
```

Comment: You said `I have no problems with displaying both models in one View`, so how do you display both models in one View currently? Perhaps you could also show your controller and view code.

Comment: You can use Tuple . http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/multiple-models-in-single-view-in-mvc/

Comment: It seems that you want to insert one record to `Plan` table and maximum 7 records to `Subject` table when you click the Create button. Assuming it's true, could you explain how the textboxes under each day relate to what will be inserted to `Subject` table? I understand that what's entered in the textbox under Hours will be inserted to `Hour` field in `Subject` table, but what if I type let's say `abcd` in the textbox under `Monday` or `Wednesday`? What will be the value in `Name` and `DayId` fields of `Subject` table for that case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best approach is to design a ViewModel class that can hold all the data on your Form that needs to be submitted, for both Plan(s) and/or Subject(s).

In the Action Method that receives this ViewModel you can pick apart the data, and based on that do whatever inserts and/or updates are needed to store it in the database.

Only the Controller should have knowledge of your database classes. All mapping between ViewModel and Database objects should be done by the controller, and the View should not be bothered or hampered by this.

Comment: I would welcome it if the downvoter has any additions or comments.

Comment: It's pure opinion that only a controller should have knowledge of database classes. People tend to subscribe to skinny controllers, fat models rather than what you claim.

Comment: Sure, it depends, but I think here it is appropriate. Useful link: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/257507/should-an-asp-net-mvc-application-directly-use-entity-framework-as-the-model

Comment: Shouldn't be downvoting an answer that isn't your opinion.  Like you say, it's pure opinion not an incorrect answer.

Comment: Thanks, i will try to add a ViewModel then.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple models can be sent to the view by combining them into a viewmodel. However, your issues seem to be different, so here goes the long answer:

As for the DB design question, I'm assuming that you're using a relational storage and one subject can be present in multiple plans so a many-to-many should be in place. You can read more on the subject [here](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php).

As for your web app, you can usually simply create a ViewModel, that contains both your desired models. If you hadn't elaborated on your question, that would be the correct answer. However, in your case, your two "model" classes are already linked, so your model can simply be a Plan.

Since I'm assuming you're using EF6 (based on your generated classes) your subjects for the plan will be posted back alongside the plan.

What I'd do is cache the currently existing subjects somewhere in your app using a [singleton](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx), and then on postback you should iterate through the cached subjects for your plan, checking if they already exist in your DB. If they don't - insert them first, if they do - simply add them to your ICollection in the plan. Then you should probably know how to insert the Plan using EF.

There are probably going to be much more bumps along the way, but you can raise new questions about those - your question as it is now is way too broad.

I'm trying to help you get something working, although it's probably not going to be ideal. Once you get it to work, I'd suggest reading on where to put business logic (and how to keep your controller small). [This](https://jonhilton.net/2016/05/23/3-ways-to-keep-your-asp-net-mvc-controllers-thin/) article could be a good start.

Another thing I'd suggest is to keep your data access in a separate layer. Goodle "3-layer architecture" and also check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rtXpYpZdOzM) on the repository pattern.

Good luck!

** Post OP-edit **

Ok, looking at your code there seem to be a lot of issues, that you'll probably want to separate into multiple questions. Here's a start:

1. There is no form on your View and you need a form and a post button on your View, and a version of your Action method on the `Controller` marked with `[Post]`. I recommend [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms) tutorial for asp.mvc core and [this](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-4-handling-form-edit-and-post-scenarios) for older versions. If you want different pages for your "edit" and "display" views, simply create separate ones, but when you're creating, you'll want to have a form.
2. For the time being, you should use a Plan as a viewModel. Typically this is not ideal, but to explain why I'd need to write a book as an answer. The resources linked should help you understand that part.
3. You seem to be using an older version of asp.net mvc (maybe I'm wrong? please tell us which one). If you want to ADD new Subjects on specific dates on the client, you'll also have to use javascript (jQuery) - or a full client-side library such as React or Angular. If you're not familiar with full frameworks stick to JQuery for now. Examine this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12203913/dynamically-adding-items-into-view-and-posting-back-to-controller-asp-net-mvc-4) to get an idea of how to achieve that.
4. You might want to separate your API methods and your plain old MVC methods into different projects.

** Edit 2 **
Seeing your Plan creation code now, you seem to have correctly read that `@Html.TextAreaFor(plan => plan.Name)` is the way to create an input that can be posted to the server.

However you're only using it for your plan name.

Instead of using textarea below (I'm assuming these are for the Subject names) use something like

```
@for(int i = 0; i < plan.Subject.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.TextAreaFor(plan => plan.Subject[i].Name)
}
```

Assuming the Plan you passed as a model to the view has any subjects, this will be the way to list them and make them editable.

Now, it seems that you want to separate them based on the day of the week, so you might want to do some filtering, for example:

```
var monday = 1;
@for(int i = 0; i < plan.Subject.Where(s => s.DayId == monday).OrderBy(s => s.Hour).Count(); i++)
```

And paste this into each of the seven columns. This will now create textareas for every subject that already exists in there.

As for dynamically creating new ones on the view, refer to point #3 above. If you don't have any subjects yet, create some fake ones in your db, just so you can render some on the client and check their source code, then follow the article I linked in #3.

Comment: That's a good start, thank you for a fast reply. But how can i retrieve subjects form the View at the first place?

Comment: Ok, just noticed your edit, will check the specific issue.

Comment: There's no form, because it's a code for displaying items, as requested in the comments. Creation view looks quite the same except the form, and empty textboxes

Comment: Created some edits, but you might also want to show where you call the [Post]Create action  on your controller.

Comment: Here you go, added the view code with form. Thank you for your time, im fairly new to MVC as you can see.