# c# How to recieve two models and send a form with one model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

First of all, this is a simplified version of my problem.

I have two models:

- Person
- Category

The problem is that I need two models. I have a form where I show the categories in a select input to then create a new Person.

In .cshtml i have:

```
@using WebApiClient.Models
@model dynamic

<h1> Form: add a person with a category</h1>

<form asp-action="formMultiple" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <label asp-for=@Model.Person.Name class="control-label">Name</label>
    <input asp-for="@Model.Person.Name" class="form-control" value= "@Model.Person.Name" />

    <label asp-for="Category" class="control-label">Category</label>
    <select asp-for="Category">
    @foreach (var item in Model.Category){
        <option value="Category">@item.NameCategory</option>
    }
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Add person" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
```

And i have in controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> formMultiple()
        {
            dynamic d = new ExpandoObject();
            var categories = await _client.GetCategoriesAsync();
            d.categories = categories;
            d.person = new Person();
            return View(d);
        }
public async Task<ActionResult> formMultiple(Person person);
```

Any ideas how to solve this problem?
Thank you <3

Comment: Did you just forget to send `d` to the view?:  `return View(d);`  Though personally I'd prefer a statically typed view model which has properties for `categories` and `person`, but technically there shouldn't be anything specifically wrong about using a `dynamic` instead.  You just lose type safety is all.

Comment: You need a `ViewModel` for your case: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/managing-data-with-viewmodel-in-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: You have a different IActionResult for each type of response.  You need a different GET for each type.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?force_isolation=true&view=aspnetcore-6.0#return-ienumerablet-or-iasyncenumerablet

Comment: @David ups, changed tty

Comment: @JoanDot: In that case what specifically is the problem?  In what way does this fail or not work as expected?

Comment: @David it says the same error as before. code error: CS1963

Comment: @JoanDot: *"the same error as before"* - No error is mentioned in the question.  Are you getting a compiler error?  A runtime exception?  Something else?  What is the exact error message?  What exact line of code produces that error?  Please clarify the question.

Comment: @RahulSharma the problem is that i need to receive it, and then send it

Comment: @David CS1963 An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I post two or more models in one form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41848763/how-can-i-post-two-or-more-models-in-one-form)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of options

1. Use a ViewModel with two properties (One for Person and One for Categories) - Best and Recommended option
2. Use a ValueTuple with two items (One for Person and One for Categories) - It should be used for small amount of data
3. Send Person Model to the view and have Categories in ViewBag or ViewData
4. Send Person Model to the view and have an ajax call to fill the Categories dropdown

So I can give you sample for the second approach

Controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> formMultiple()
{
    var categories = await _client.GetCategoriesAsync();
    var person = new Person();
    var model = (person, categories);
    return View(model );
}
```

View

```html
@using WebApiClient.Models
@model (Person person, List<Category> categories)

<h1> Form: add a person with a category</h1>

<form asp-action="formMultiple" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <label asp-for=person.Name class="control-label">Name</label>
    <input asp-for="person.Name" name="@nameof(Model.person.Name)" class="form-control" />

    <label asp-for="person.Category" name="@nameof(Model.person.Category)" class="control-label">Category</label>
    <select asp-for="person.Category">
    @foreach (var item in Model.categories){
        <option value="@item.IdCategory">@item.NameCategory</option>
    }
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Add person" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
```

If you can share your Person and Category  model, then I can provide more precise code

Comment: I was going to accept this answer because now it retrieves the data from categories, but now there is a problem that it doesn't receive the information in public async Task<ActionResult> formMultiple(Person person);. There is something that needs to be changed there? Thank you so much :D

Comment: It recieves all the values with null

Comment: Let me try to fix it

Comment: Because before i just took "person" var (in the validation method) and then send it to the webapi and it work. Now when that method is executed, it appears all the values in null.

Comment: The problem is with the "name" attributes for html form elements. these must match the Post method's model property names. I have updated the code. See Razor view changes

Comment: thank you so much <3 (idk why i deleted this msg)

Answer (score 2):

Based on a comment above:

> CS1963 An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation

Don't rely on `dynamic` for your view models.  It's trivial to create classes which give you all of the static type safety that C# generally expects.  `dynamic` can be a useful tool, but is not a drop-in replacement for anywhere you don't want to create a class.

Your view model could be as simple as (I'm guessing on a reasonable name):

```
public class CreatePersonVM
{
    public IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

Then you'd expect that type in the view:

```
@model CreatePersonVM
```

And supply it from the controller:

```
var model = new CreatePersonVM();
model.Categories = await _client.GetCategoriesAsync();
model.Person = new Person();
return View(model);
```

Just ensure that the elements in the `<form>` still create a `Person` object and that form can still post the values for that object to the POST action.